# NSUserDefaults not saving properly

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to programming and I have the following problem I was hoping someone could help with. I have an app that uses a loggin to access the main menu. I would like the app to store the users name (from the login screen) and use it within the program. If the user has already logged in they don't have to log in again, ever. I want the app to check if the user has logged in on start up and go directly to the menu menu if they have.

My problem is at present if they press the login button they go straight to main menu without entering login details. If they enter they name I can use their name within the app until the app is restarted and the info is gone.

OK here is my new code but I still have the same problem.

```
-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *tempstr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]      objectForKey:@"username"];

    if (tempstr.length == 0) {
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setObject:name.text forKey:@"username"];
        [prefs synchronize];
        [self showCorrectController];

        ClubFindViewController *logView = [[ClubFindViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"ClubFindViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:logView animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        MainMenuView *mainView = [[MainMenuView alloc]     initWithNibName:@"MainMenuView" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:mainView animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self showCorrectController];
}

-(void)showCorrectController {
    UIViewController *viewController = nil;

    if ([self isLoggedIn]) {
        viewController = [[MainMenuView alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        viewController = [[ClubFindViewController alloc] init];
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
     viewController = nil;
}

-(BOOL)isLoggedIn {
    return ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriecated. Thanks.

Comment: Your app supports only one user? You app has the option for the user to log out? Are you setting the value of `"username"` key to `nil` when the user logs out? Why is there double `!` in the return statement of *isLoggedIn* method?

Comment: @EmptyStack Double `!` will convert `nil` to `NO`. So technically that wasn't a mistake. Not sure why that was edited out. Current version is incorrect.

Comment: @Deepak, Double `!` should convert `nil` to `YES`. Isn't it? ;-) Anyway the OP is correct about the double `!`

Comment: @EmptyStack `!!nil` is `!YES` which is `NO` right? And your answer is just a verbose version of it.

Comment: @Deepak, Yes. You are right. Confused! ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender {` You should check if they have entered text, If not, prompt again. 
In your case if the user presses 'Login' without entering name, the 'username' value will have empty string and the login will go through.

Comment: Yes my app only supports one user. Yes the app has the option for the user to log out. Yes I think Iam setting the value of 'username' to nil when they log out. I have added an if statement to check if text is entered but I still have the same problem.@Shreesh @EmptyStack